# Proving if a transformation is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a terrible understanding of Linear Algebra so I'm trying every resource out there that I can. Hopefully my questions won't come off as idiotic.

Anyway, we have a transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$ such that:

$T(x,y)$ outputs $(3x-y+1, -x)$.

We want to prove whether or not this transformation is linear.
I understand that in order for a transformation to be linear, it must satisfy:

1) $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$

2)$T(cx) = cT(x)$

I am just a little confused by what is meant by $T(x+y)$.

Is it just $T(x+y) = (3x-y+1-x)$?

Then $T(x) = (3x-y+1)$ and $T(y) = (-x)$ so it is obvious that $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$ proving this transformation preserves the addition structure?

Basically, I'm just confused about the notation.

Comment: You are introducing confusion by reusing the same symbols with a different meaning. Your condition 1) should read $T((x, y)+(u, v))=T((x,y)) + T((u, v))$ as $T$ applies to a pair.

Comment: This makes sense in light of Andreas' comment about how x,y are pairs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's linear, you should have $T(0, 0) = (0, 0)$, whereas here $T(0,0) = (1.0)$.

$T$ is affine instead.

---

As to your doubt about $T(x+y)$, note that $x, y$ are pairs here, say $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$. So
$$
T(x + y) = T ((x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2)) = T (x_1 + y_1, x_2+y_2) = (3(x_1 + y_1) - (x_2+y_2) + 1, - (x_1 + y_1)).
$$
So you should prove that for all $x, y$ you have
$$
T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y),
$$
that is
$$
(3(x_1 + y_1) - (x_2+y_2) + 1, - (x_1 + y_1)) = 
(3 x_1 - x_2 + 1, -x_1) + (3 y_1 - y_2 + 1, - y_2)
=
(3(x_1 + y_1) - (x_2+y_2) + 2, - (x_1 + y_1)).
$$
Now you see the two formulas do not match. This is apparent if you set $x_i = y_i = 0$, as you get $1 = 2$.

Comment: "Affine" is a term I haven't learned yet. I will do my best to look it up right now! Thank you.

Comment: Well, no, you should prove that the two properties that you correctly listed hold for all $x, y$. I will expand my answer.